# Cascaded Drop Down with OOTB SP Foundation?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I'm using SP2010 Foundation. Corporate governance forbids customization beyond stylesheets controlling fonts/colors/etc. No access to Visual Studio or SP Designer, so I'm looking for some out-of-the-box thinking to help me achieve my intended results with OOTB SharePoint. That's the world in which I'm working.

We have a catalog of job aids as List Items. The items are composed of a `Title`, a text field for the Job Aid `Content` and a dropdown box choice for a `Category`. Now, we're looking at adding a second column for a `Subcategory`. Legacy items will be easy to change in datasheet view, but I'm trying to modify the manner in which new items are entered. As a new job aid is created, I would like the `Subcategory` to be based on the entered `Category`. For instance, if the main category is `Billing/Payment`, my subcategories are limited **only** to `Payments`, `Account` and `Refunds`. I don't want to see `Payment Arrangements` which is a subcategory of `Collections`.

I can envision a series of separate lists, `BillingSubCats`, `CollectionsSubcats` etc., each list containing the relevant `SubCategories` for a specific `Category. But how would I force`BillingSubCats`to populate the dialog drop down when Category` has been selected as `Billing`?

Perhaps I could do a single `Subcategory` list and some sort of validation check BASED on the `Category` column.

Before I proceed, I'd like to know if my requirements are even possible without some sort of scripting or SPD work. If so, what's the best way to proceed on this?

Comment: It is called Cascaded Drop downs, FYI

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri - Thanks! just updated my title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI - It is called **Cascaded Drop downs**

I seriously doubt it will be possible with OOTB SharePoint, with out injecting any JavaScript/JQuery or Development... Since it is SharePoint Foundation 2010, you even won't have InfoPath based forms as they are in SharePoint Standard/Enterprise!

However, if you change your mind or policy for doing some JavaScript/JQuery:
[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is one that can help, and here is [Cascaded Drop Down section](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)

You should wait for other people to answer this question, this is completely based on my personal experience... Maybe I missed something!