# Calculated Lookup from another Lookup

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, custom-list, lookup-column, office-365

I'm sure this has probably come up before but I'm getting nowhere fast so I thought I'd ask the question!

I have a list called Areas, which has an Area column (text).

I have a second list called Managers, which has a Manager column (person field) and an Area column (lookup field to the Area list).

This works great and will allow the users to keep the areas updated and the managers (and their related area) updated.

What I need to do now is, on a new list have a column that is a lookup to area.  When the area is selected I need a second column to automagically populate the manager name related to that area.  And that's where I am stuck!  Can this be done?  I understand that lookups cannot be used in calculated fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cascaded Drop Down with OOTB SP Foundation?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58149/cascaded-drop-down-with-ootb-sp-foundation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with OOB Sharepoint.